# Lost contacts after turning off Exchange

Tags: exchange

On my iPhone, I gave it to another person who used it and added contacts.  Later I turned off the calendar, contacts, ets. (he didn't have the password) but some of his contacts disappeared.  Can I recover them?

Answer (score 1):

When you delete Exchange account, sync deletes all of the contacts that are stored trough it. You can try to set up Exchange again to get that contacts synced on the phone (you said there is no password assigned) and then use this guide to keep them stored after turning off the Exchange account http://iphone-contacts.blogspot.com/2013/03/keep-your-exchange-contacts-on-your.html

Answer (score 1):

### Method #1

Go to settings/icloud on your phone.  Make sure you are logged with your Apple ID.

Contacts should be on, click on it to turn it off and choose keep (even though you show no contacts)

When the process is done go ahead and turn on contacts again, choose merge.  All your contacts should show up if you had a previous backup to icloud.

The difficulty in restoring iCloud data from a back up is that the back up is older than the current version on iCloud and anything that is restored gets removed again when an iCloud sync occurs.

[Source](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3899761?start=0)

### Method #2

1. Ensure the device is connected to your local network.
2. Start the restore from iCloud back up.
3. Allow the devices settings to restore (watch for the confirmation of
   completion).
4. As the apps begin to restore, disconnect your Internet (e.g. pull the connection to your router WAN port - the one that goes to the telephone point).
5. Wait for the time out confirmation.
6. Navigate to settings > iCloud and turn off contact syncing (keep
   contacts when prompted).
7. Reconnect the router to the internet and let the restore process
   complete.
8. Delete any iCloud contacts from iCloud.com on a computer.
9. Navigate to settings > iCloud and turn on contact syncing (merge
   contacts when prompted).

May I suggest that you carry out a back up to iTunes before you try anything, that way should things become even worse, you can at least restore iPhone contacts back to where you are now.

[Source](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5783644?tstart=0)